# Сравнение двух List на одинаковые элементы

Tags: c#, list

Поступила задача, есть первый список:

`List<String>   ("1","5","9").`

Есть второй список:

`List<String>("1","14","9","5")`

Нужно сравнить второй `List` на содержание всех символов из первого. То, есть если во втором `List` присутствуют `1, 5, 9` ,то вывести сообщение! Пробовал вложенными циклами пройтись по этим листам,но это как то не получается. Как решить такую задачу?

Comment: Покажите, что вы пробовали. Также непонятно, что именно нужно выводить: толи разные элементы (из первого? из второго?), толи общие. А раз непонятно, какие требования -- то и решать непонятно что невозможно.

Comment: `if (list2.Intersect(list1).SequenceEqual(list1)) Console.WriteLine("!!!");`

Comment: Продемонстрируй нерабочий вариант, а мы уже подскажем - что в нём можно исправить. Сейчас ваш вопрос звучит так - как узнать, что второй список включает все элементы из первого списка. И я не вижу никаких проблем которые могли бы возникнуть при реализации.

Comment: Это нужно для фильтра, например в Листе фильтра("Парковка","CТО")!!   А объект содержит Лист("Парковка","Мойка")!То есть,если в фильтре указали Парковка и Сто параметры поиска,то это объект не покажется,так как у него только Парковка совпадает с параметрами поиска

Comment: @АндрейNOP, SequenceEqual не нужен, достаточно длину полученную сравнить

Comment: @Grundy, ошибаетесь. `SequenceEqual` прервет перебор при первом несовпадении, а `Count` в любом случае будет перебирать до конца

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я почему-то думал там будет не IEnumerable

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо,сам решил проблемку!!! Как и писал ранее, перебираю во вложенных циклах, и итерирую счетчик(создал int) -который в конце сравнивает свое значение с размером Листа.То есть поиск на количество совпадений.

Comment: Не надо описывать код, прикладывай его

Comment: а как здесь код вставить?

Comment: Скопировать из своего редактора и вставить в сообщение, выделить и нажать Ctrl+K. По необходимости доформатировать.